# CSS parameters for Internet Explorer doesn't work

Tags: css

I have different css styles made for internet explorer to show website properly.

I tried to add tried to add numerous codes into wordpress header php before it worked in Internet Explorer But the problem is that the additional style is read by all browsers, so if the style works in IE, the same stlye works on all browsers.

Is there any way to use one style.css and only set this entry for internet explorer:

```
#header .menu li {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 40px; 
}
```

If I put that to the header.php

```
<![if !IE]>
    <style> #header .menu li {
         float: left;
         margin-left: 40px; 
        }
    </style>
<![endif]>
```

It overrides additional style.css, so it means that Chrome also obeys this parameters. My site url is virmodrosti.com

Let me know what to do, thank you.

Comment: Your conditional comment is excluding IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Target ALL VERSIONS of IE

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

> Target everything EXCEPT IE

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="not-ie.css" />
 <!--<![endif]-->
```

> Resource :https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: The first one doesnt work, so only the oposite way it works. To use the code to target everything except ie. Is there no way to include some media style for ie inside css file?

Comment: @Techuser, i am happy for help you.you can insert css rules in css file and link it to main file.